# Is it possible to have the CustomValidator get fired before the RequiredFieldValidators

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, customvalidator

I have a textbox in which user enters the jobnumber. I am checking if this number exists in the database, by using a server side CustomValidator. I want this CustomValidator to be called before anything else in the page. Right now it is firing the CustomValidator only if all the RequiredFieldValidators are validated to true. And the validation is happening on button click.

Is it possible to validate CustomValidator before the other RequiredFieldValidators? Also, is there a way in which, as soon as the jobnumber is entered into the textbox, we can validate the number and display an error if it is invalid, immediately and not wait until the button click?

Comment: Very likely, the requiredFieldValidator is running (also) at client side (javascript) and if not fullfilled, it stops the postback, i.e. your server side CustomValidator is not run at all. you maybe need to implement some client side validation as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `CustomValidator`, then set the [`ValidateEmptyText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext) property to true and add code to your validation method to check if the value is populated. Then you don't need the `RequiredFieldValidator` at all. Just make sure you have a JavaScript function to do the validation client-side and set the [`ClientValidationFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction) property.

To trigger the validation whenever you want , you can use the method described here (although I've never tried it): http://fczaja.blogspot.ca/2009/07/aspnet-how-to-trigger-client-side.html

```
function Validate()
{
    // Get the specific validator element
    var validator = document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator1');

    // Validate chosen validator
    ValidatorValidate(validator);

    // Update validation summary for chosen validation group
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
    ValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup);    
}
```

Then you can use that in the [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) event of the textbox.